# GMail API Batch insert messages throws - java.io.IOException: insufficient data written

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

I'm trying to batch insert 38 messages into Gmail using Gmail `RESTFul API` and getting this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3214)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:241)
```

What does it means and how can I fix this?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do some or all of these 38 messages have attachments? I'd like to have some idea of the size of the messages you are inserting.

Comment: @kroikie - Yes, tried now, there is a batch with 7 messages, the one of them is about 13mb (RAW) and I got this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Years later I ran into this and successfully troubleshot it.  For future generations, this is due to the individual message or -  if you're batching requests- the entire batch of messages being over the
 25mb size limit.  This has nothing to do with your connection.

Reduce the number of items in your batches or do a check on the message size total before adding it to the batch.  If it's over 25 MB then it will fail the entire batch.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error about 2 dozen times while importing 8000+ emails, probably due to a deficient network connection on my end, not much you can do except retry in case of IOException (but not retry in case of 400 Bad Request).

Comment: Well, they have to make error messages more clear, otherwise it's hard to debug, by the way exponential backoff retry is not helping here and I think my internet connection is pretty good, so maybe the problem is not the internet connection.

Comment: There are just some simple limitations on size allowed by Google APIs unfortunately.  You shouldn't try to send more than 25MB in a single request. Any HTTP 5xx error you should retry with backoff (and the two or three 4xx errors related to throttling/quota limits).